# vertical-align content in middle of nested column (bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I want my content (H3 + p) to be in the middle (horizontally and vertically) of their `<div class="col-md-12 inside-row">`.

I tried to display: flex and align-items: center. It did positioned my content in the middle of my `<div>` but then the whole column was starting from the top of my page and was over my header...

The class .vertical-align was to center (vertically and horizontally) my header and it worked well.

I am working with Bootstrap.

Thanks for you help!

here is my HTML:

```
<section>
 <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <img src="icons/blue-bezier.gif" alt="icon1">
                    <img src="icons/blue-network.gif" alt="icon2">
                    <img src="icons/blue-layers.gif" alt="icon3">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="col-md-12 inside-row">
                        <h3>Plan for the long term</h3>
                        <p>Launch universal, fungible, and programmable digital assets. Utilize our smart contract platform for fraud-prouf P2P trading, uncrackable DRM, esports services &amp; active viral marketing.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 inside-row">
                        <h3>Proof of Play is a purpose-built system for game currency</h3>
                        <p>A decentralized network that scales down to mobile and provides a cryptographically accurate count of players online. PoP determines a fixed issuance rate based on real gameplay.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 inside-row">
                        <h3>Backed by the security of Ethereum</h3>
                        <p>A turing complete platform with numerous pre optimized contract templates.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>    
</section>
```

and my CSS:

```
.vertical-center {
    min-height: 100%;  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
    min-height: 100vh; /* These two lines are counted as one */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.row {
    height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
section .inside-row {
    height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
section img {
    width: 40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind adding extra markup, one way to this is to just add a wrapper around your content

```
...
<div class="col-md-12 inside-row">
  <div>
      <h3>Plan for the long term</h3>
      <p>Launch universal, fungible, and programmable digital assets. Utilize our smart contract platform for fraud-prouf P2P trading, uncrackable DRM, esports services &amp; active viral marketing.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and do

```
.inside-row > * {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```